# reflection of the Identity matrix,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

It is a simple question; I was wondering if the following matrices have a will-known name (other than it is a reflection of the identity matrix), or a notation, like

$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

and

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: they are also square roots or fourth roots of the identity matrix

Comment: These are strongly related to the Pauli matrices: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices